# python BeautifulSoup4 - why does result print 5 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do some web scraping in python using BeautifulSoup 4.

I am trying to scrape the salary of an public employee. I am doing that successfully but the result is returned 5 times and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the website I am scraping: https://data.richmond.com/salaries/2018/state/university-of-virginia/tony-bennett

Here is my code example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



source = requests.get(f'https://data.richmond.com/salaries/2018/state/university-of-virginia/tony-bennett')

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
main_box = soup.find_all('div')

for i in main_box:
    try:
        x = i.find('div', class_='col-12 col-lg-4 pay')
        z = x.find('h2').text
        print(z)

    except Exception:
        pass
```

And my results are:

```
$525,000
$525,000
$525,000
$525,000
$525,000
```

This is the correct salary, but as I said the results print 5 times.

If I go to the page, right click, and 'inspect' I find the class I am looking for, which is 'col-12 col-lg-4 pay' and then within that the 'h2' tag. There is only one 'h2' tag. And print the text of that.

So it seems I am missing something, but what?

Comment: Is the `h2` nested inside of 5 divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just get rid of the for loop and use a more specific find query

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get(f'https://data.richmond.com/salaries/2018/state/university-of-virginia/tony-bennett')

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
main_box = soup.find("div", {"class": "pay"})
print(main_box.find('h2').text)
```

Comment: Thanks!  How does this syntax {'class': 'pay'} work inside the .find() function?  Can you explain a little more?

Comment: In this specific case it finds the first div with the class "pay". You could also use this with find_all to get a list of divs that have the class "pay".    It also looks like there is a newer notation of soup.find("div", class_ = "pay") but for now both seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract this is by using CSS

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://data.richmond.com/salaries/2018/state/university-of-virginia/tony-bennett'

res = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res , 'html.parser')

Value = soup.select('#paytotal')
print(Value[0].text)
```